# Rails 3 Custom Validation for Email Uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am using Riak database for my current project which does not support the "uniqueness" helper method. Now I want to validate user email for uniqueness. How to write the custom validation for unique emial address??

Comment: Please have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888009/ripple-with-devise

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this. You may have to modify the `User.exists?` part if that doesn't work with your DB.

```
class User
  validate :verify_unique_email

  def verify_unique_email
    if User.exists? email: email
      errors.add :email, 'has already been taken'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: "exists?" method is not supported in Riak

Comment: Like I said - you may have to modify that query. However you test whether a record exists with a particular value, do that. If you find one, add the error as I've shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this in your validator:

```
Class User
  validate :unique_email_address?

  def unique_email_address?
    return false if User.where(email: self.email).any?
  end

end
```

Let me know if you need help with the custom validator file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Rails 7.

```
class User
  validate :verify_unique_email

  def verify_unique_email
    if !User.find_by(email: email).nil?
      errors.add :email, 'has already been taken'
      throw :abort
    end
  end
end
```